# Javascript array displays twice

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to show the filters selected from a checkbox. First I'm creating an array of values selected from the checkboxes and I'm trying to append to a string

For example I have two checkboxes labeled: `label1` and `label2`, I built the array `['label1','label2']`.

The desired result would be "`Filtered by: Label1, Label2`" but instead I get `Filtered by: Label1,Label2, Label1,Label2`

I guess it's something in the for loop where I'm trying to build the string, because the array looks fine

```
let topLabel = jQuery('.industry-filter').data('selected-text') + ' ';
let termsName= ['Industry', 'Category']
if(termsName.length){
  for(var j = 0; j < termsName.length; j++){
    if(j == termsName.length - 1){
      topLabel += termsName;
    }else{
      topLabel += termsName+', ';
    }
  }
}else{
  topLabel = jQuery('.industry-filter').data('text');
}

$('.industry-filter').text(topLabel);
```

Here is a pen that shows the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqjYxL

Comment: You forgot to access the array element using the index `if(j == termsName.length - 1){
      topLabel += termsName[j];
    }else{
      topLabel += termsName[j]+', ';
    }`

Comment: how about use join instead 
`termsName.join(", ", termsName)` you're just making your code complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access one element by its *index*.

```
if(j == termsName.length - 1){
  topLabel += termsName[j];
}else{
  topLabel += termsName[j]+', ';
}
```

One short version of your solution could be using `join` method.

```
if(termsName.length){
   topLabel += termsName.join(',')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You need to access by index.**

Without using index you're assigning the complete array.

```
let topLabel = jQuery('.industry-filter').data('selected-text') + ' ';
let termsName= ['Industry', 'Category']
if(termsName.length){
  for(var j = 0; j < termsName.length; j++){
    if(j == termsName.length - 1){
      topLabel += termsName[j];
                           ^^^
    }else{
      topLabel += termsName[j] +', ';
                           ^^^
    }
  }
}else{
  topLabel = jQuery('.industry-filter').data('text');
}

$('.industry-filter').text(topLabel);
```